# Spark DataFrame Zeppelin read folders

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I am working in Scala with google storage and Zeppelin, I can load all my json files by using the next query.

```
sqlContext.read.json("gs://myBucket/*/jsonfile.json")
```

My data is structured in to small chunks, where each chunk got it's own folder in `myBucket`. In chunk folder I got files related to that chunk

- jsonfile.json
- otherData.data
- moreJsons.json

I want to get all my folders paths and than process in different process/task...
So I be able to do some thing like that:

```
if(isJson){
    sqlContext.read.json("gs://myBucket/chunkId/jsonfile.json")
}
```

In this example I know the chank path: `chunkId` and, I got some inner logic for `isJson.

So this is what I need(I hope it is some how clear...) and my question is: **How do I get a list of folders without reading the file content?**

Answer (score 0):

Spark has no built-in mechanism for listing the files. You can use whatever mechanism you want to do this. For example, if Google Storage is mapped via a Hadoop filesystem you can use the Hadoop APIs. Use your cluster to implement a fast breadth-first file traversal, e.g., something like the following, which we use for quick ad hoc tasks at [Swoop](http://swoop.com).

[Distributed file listing using Spark and the Hadoop filesystem APIs](https://gist.github.com/ssimeonov/3fa68144d4be4d94521a84f91e28669d)